# What is the IUPAC nomenclature of alkane with large numbers of C atoms (more than 200)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

What is the IUPAC nomenclature for alkanes with large numbers of $\ce{C}$ atoms (more than 200)? For example, what is the IUPAC accepted name for $\ce{C_{205}H_{412}}$?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The definitive answer is, of course, in the rules established by the IUPAC’s “Commission on nomenclature in organic chemistry”. The reference you are looking for is:

> “Extension of Rules A-1.1 and A-2.5 Concerning Numerical Terms Used in Organic Chemical Nomenclature”, *Pure Appl. Chem.*, **1986**, *58*, 1693-1696

which can be found [here as a PDF](http://www.iupac.org/publications/pac/1986/pdf/5812x1693.pdf) and [here as an HTML version](http://www.chem.qmul.ac.uk/iupac/misc/numb.html). In particular:

> NT-1.1 - The fundamental numerical terms for use in hydrocarbon names or as multiplying prefixes for simple features are given in the following list:
>
> \begin{array}{|c:c|c:c|c:c|c:c|}\hline
>     1&\rm \text{mono- or hen-} &10 &\rm \text{deca-}&100&\rm \text{hecta-}& 1000&\rm \text{kilia-} \\\hline
>     2&\rm \text{di- or do-}&20&\rm \text{icosa-}&200&\rm \text{dicta-}&2000&\rm \text{dilia-}\\\hline
>     3&\rm \text{tri-}& 30&\rm \text{triaconta-}&300&\rm \text{tricta-}&3000&\rm \text{trilia-} \\\hline
>     4&\rm \text{tetra-}&40&\rm \text{tetraconta-}&400&\rm \text{tetracta-}&4000&\rm \text{tetralia-} \\\hline
>     5&\rm \text{penta-}&50&\rm \text{pentaconta-}&500&\rm \text{pentacta-}&5000&\rm \text{pentalia-}\\\hline
>     6&\rm \text{hexa-}&60&\rm \text{hexaconta-}&600&\rm \text{hexacta-}&6000&\rm \text{hexalia-}\\\hline
>     7&\rm \text{hepta-}&70&\rm \text{heptaconta-}&700&\rm \text{heptacta-}&7000&\rm \text{heptalia-}\\\hline
>     8&\rm \text{octa-}&80&\rm \text{octaconta-}&800&\rm \text{ octacta-}&8000&\rm \text{octalia-}\\\hline
>     9&\rm \text{nona-}&90&\rm \text{nonaconta-}&900&\rm \text{nonacta-}&9000&\rm \text{nonalia-}\\\hline
> \end{array}

So, $\ce{C_205H_412}$ is the molecular formula of pentadictane. $\ce{C_7547H_15096}$ is heptatetracontapentactaheptaliane.

Answer (score 4):

Presuming it is linear, then it should follow the trend of the [higher alkanes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_alkanes).

For $\ce{C10}:  \ce{CH3(CH2)8CH3}$ - the name is decane (*deca* means *ten*).

For $\ce{C20}:  \ce{CH3(CH2)18CH3}$ - the name is icosane (*icos* means *twenty*)

For $\ce{C25}:  \ce{CH3(CH2)23CH3}$ - the name is pentacosane

After icosane, the higher alkanes follow the following:

For $\ce{C30}:  \ce{CH3(CH2)28CH3}$ - the name is triacontane

For $\ce{C40}:  \ce{CH3(CH2)38CH3}$ - the name is tetracontane

For $\ce{C50}:  \ce{CH3(CH2)48CH3}$ - the name is pentacontane

So...

For $\ce{C100}:  \ce{CH3(CH2)98CH3}$ - the name would be decacontane

For $\ce{C200}:  \ce{CH3(CH2)198CH3}$ - the name would probably be icosacontane

And for $\ce{C205}:  \ce{CH3(CH2)203CH3}$ - the name might be **pentacosacontane**

Comment: From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_straight-chain_alkanes), the name for $C_{100}$ is hectane.